# Self tracking for Android?

Tags: applications

I would like to do [self-tracking](http://quantifiedself.com/self-tracking/) on Android (ICS). Specifically: enter physical tension spots (forehead, hand, back, etc..) every hour or so, and then see plotted graphs and statistical insights on the accumulated data over days.

As an added bonus, I want to manipulate the data from [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) scripts (e.g., read data and plot using PIL in Python, or jquery plot in webkit).

Is it possible? None of the Android apps listed in [that site](http://quantifiedself.com/guide/tag/Android) seem to do what I want.

Comment: The same site has a set of posts for Android based tools - http://quantifiedself.com/guide/tag/Android

Comment: @Sparx i already looked into that url before posting here; none of the apps mentioned in that page does what specifically i asked in the question.

Comment: What about entering the data in an Excel spreadsheet and then plotting the graphs?

Comment: "Is there an app that does X" questions are generally not considered a good fit here. Please review the [FAQ].